# Callback with two methods is not working between NonActivity class and a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, callback

I have created a callback via interface with two methods. The callback is between a NonActivity class and a Fragment. The problem is that only one interface method invisible is being called. And the other interface method visible is not called. I have copied the code of interface and both classes. **MY OBJECTIVE IS THAT BOTH CALLBACK METHODS INVISIBLE() AND VISIBLE() SHOULD BE CALLED AT DIFFERENT TIMES WHEN TRIGGERED**. I am somewhat confused about not getting the particular functionality.

```
public interface MyCustomListener {
    void invisible();
    void visible();
}
```

The NonActivity class code is as follows:

```
public class Operations {    
    private Context context;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    private MyCustomListener listener;

    public void setMyCustomListener(MyCustomListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public Operations(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    }

    public void getView(int number) {

        Perform pa = new Perform(context);
        Long count = pa.count(number);

        if (count > 0) {
            ArrayList arrayList = pa.getAllList(number);
            adapter = new AdapterMovie(context, arrayList, recyclerView, number);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            if (listener != null)
                listener.invisible();
        } 
        else if (count < 1) {
            recyclerView.setAdapter(null);

            if (listener != null)
                listener.visible();
        }
    }
}
```

The Fragment class code is as follows:

```
public class Frag extends Fragment {
    private int fragmentNumber = 0;

    private Operations fo;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView message;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
        fo = new Operations(getActivity(), recyclerView);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        fo.setMyCustomListener(new MyCustomListener() {
            @Override
            public void invisible() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "invisible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void visible() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: check your count var  Long count = pa.count(number); is 0 to meet condition . else if (count < 1) {}

Comment: are you sure your   "if condition" works perfectly???

Comment: Yes, the if condition is working fine!

Comment: When does `Operations.getView(int number)` get called?

Comment: @MidasLefko it refreshes the recyclerview and display the cards

Comment: The `if else if` blocks you could easily replace with an `if else` block. It's less confusing. Then the code of `Perform` might be relevant. Have you debugged the code, setting a break point in `getView(int)`?

Comment: any other solutions

Comment: Are you sure `Operations.getView(int number)` is being called?

Answer (score 0):

If you want get callback in fragment, you should implements your fragment from `MyCustomListener`. then you pass fragment to constructor of Operations.

fragment such as below:

```
     public class Frag extends Fragment implements MysCustomListener{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
        fo = new Operations(this, recyclerView);
        return view;
    }
    @override
    void invisible(){
    }
    @override
    void visible(){
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please write the code .. i am still confused

Comment: tried to do it with your way but still  not working

Comment: You also have to set the listener from the fragment. Add `fo.setMyCustomListener(this)` after creating the `fo` object in the fragment

Comment: you should implement your fragments from interface MysCustomListener. and when create operation instance, replace 'getActivity()' with this.